# Datatables button group dropdown-menu hover min-width too big

Tags: css, datatables

I am not sure how to handle this breaking style issue after updating DataTables. This style issue did not appear for me in an older version of DataTables.

I have a custom DataTable using bootstrap 4 theme with various included libraries (see included libraries below). On the table I add a dropdown button group. When hovering a dropdown menu item, the hover background extends past the dropdown menu container caused by the following DataTables CDN style.

```
div.dt-button-collection .dt-button {
    min-width: 200px;
}
```

I can override the dropdown-menu style by adding a single pixel to the dropdown-menu width, but **I would like to know if this is an acceptable fix on my part, or if this is a reportable DataTables breaking change issue.**

```
/* override */
div.dt-button-collection .dt-button {
  min-width: auto !important;
}
```

> **Previous version**
>
> This combined file was created by the DataTables downloader builder:
> https://datatables.net/download
>
> To rebuild or modify this file with the latest versions of the
> included software please visit:
> https://datatables.net/download/#bs4/jszip-2.5.0/dt-1.10.18/b-1.5.6/b-flash-1.5.6/b-html5-1.5.6/b-print-1.5.6/cr-1.5.0/fh-3.1.4/kt-2.5.0/r-2.2.2/rr-1.2.4/sc-2.0.0/sl-1.3.0
>
> Included libraries: JSZip 2.5.0, DataTables 1.10.18, Buttons 1.5.6,
> Flash export 1.5.6, HTML5 export 1.5.6, Print view 1.5.6, ColReorder
> 1.5.0, FixedHeader 3.1.4, KeyTable 2.5.0, Responsive 2.2.2, RowReorder 1.2.4, Scroller 2.0.0, Select 1.3.0

> **Updated version**
>
> This combined file was created by the DataTables downloader builder:
> https://datatables.net/download
>
> To rebuild or modify this file with the latest versions of the
> included software please visit:
> https://datatables.net/download/#bs4/jszip-2.5.0/dt-1.12.1/b-2.2.3/b-html5-2.2.3/b-print-2.2.3/cr-1.5.6/date-1.1.2/fh-3.2.4/kt-2.7.0/r-2.3.0/rr-1.2.8/sc-2.0.7/sb-1.3.4/sp-2.0.2/sl-1.4.0
>
> Included libraries: JSZip 2.5.0, DataTables 1.12.1, Buttons 2.2.3,
> HTML5 export 2.2.3, Print view 2.2.3, ColReorder 1.5.6, DateTime
> 1.1.2, FixedHeader 3.2.4, KeyTable 2.7.0, Responsive 2.3.0, RowReorder 1.2.8, Scroller 2.0.7, SearchBuilder 1.3.4, SearchPanes 2.0.2, Select 1.4.0

**My jsbin**

https://jsbin.com/mefuwey/edit?html,output

Comment: I would report the issue, and mention the workaround. Take a look at [this guide](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/12899/post-test-cases-when-asking-for-help-please-read) first, if you have not already seen it.